# Migrate multiple vmdk to openstack

Tags: image, virtual-machine, vmware, openstack, vmdk

I have a running vm in vmware environment and need to migrate that vm to openstack environment(qcow2).

I exported my virtual machine and it created 3 vmdks files, now how can I install this 3 vmdk files in to openstack environment. I have converted these 3 vmdks files to qcow2 format but how can I handle 3 qcow2 image to install my vm.

Could someone guide please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try create server with `--block-device-mapping`, check from "[Block Device Mapping in Nova](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/queens/user/block-device-mapping.html)".

Like this:

```
openstack server create --flavor FLAVOR.NAME --image qcow2.first.vmdk \
 --block-device-mapping vdb=qcow2.second_1.vmdk:image \
 --block-device-mapping vdc=qcow2.third_2.vmdk:image \
 --nic port-id=the_port_with_same_ip_as_in_vmware \
 qcow2_image_server_name
```

In my situation, we use `ceph` to provide the shared storage, so I use `volume` instead of the `image` in above command line, it works for me. I think it's similar with local disk storage like your scenario.

Another thing, I had test that `ceph shared storage` could transform to `local disk storage` with replace the disk's file by `qemu-img convert`, vice versa.